# PHP Uploading Files

Tags: php, html, file, upload, file-upload

I'm having a problem uploading files in PHP.  When I submit, $_FILES[] is empty.  I feel like this is such a n00b question :/

My form:

```
<form method="post" action="uploadfile.php">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="300000" />
Image: <input name="ImageFile" type="file" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Add Image" /><br />
</form>
```

Relevant php.ini:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; File Uploads ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; Whether to allow HTTP file uploads.
file_uploads = On

; Temporary directory for HTTP uploaded files (will use system default if not
; specified).
upload_tmp_dir = "c:\php5\upload\"

; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 300M
```

c:\php5\upload\ is writable by IUSR_HOSTNAME

Any thoughts on what else I should check?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Make sure your form tag has this attribute: `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Without it the files will not get uploaded.

Comment: We have a winner!  Thank you, sir!  I can't uparrow because I'm a noob, but I would if I could!

Comment: No problem. Welcome to the site. :)