# Uploading files with PHP

Tags: php, html

I am using a form for users to upload files to my website. I want to allow them to upload multiple photos at once, so I am using the HTML5 "multiple" attribute.

My HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="save.php">
    <input type="file" name="uploads[]" multiple="multiple" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

save.php:

```
<?php
  foreach ($_FILES['uploads']['name'] as $file) {
    echo $file . "<br/>";
    $file= time() . $_FILES['uploads']['name'];
    $target= UPLOADPATH . $file;
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploads']['tmp_name'], $target)
    or die('error with query 2');
   }
```

But, for some reason when I run the script, I get an error saying undefined index: uploads. And an error saying that I have an invalid argument supplied for foreach(). What could I be dong wrong?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

Okay, setting the `enctype="mulitpart/form-data"` worked. Now, I am having trouble with moving the file. I am getting the error `move_uploaded_file() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks again

Comment: Should it not be `foreach ($_FILES['uploads[]']['name'] as $file) {` ?

Comment: @sgroves: No.  When `[]` is used in a form name, it becomes an array.

Comment: Oh, I would have thought the multiple attribute would have taken care of that. Never used multi-upload before.

Comment: Exact dublicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/823211/php-uploading-files

Comment: @sgroves: The `multiple` attribute is an HTML5 thing.  It lets you select multiple files without needing multiple `<input>`s, nothing to do with PHP.  As far as PHP is concerned, you *do* have multiple `<input>`s, so you need the `[]` to make it an array, otherwise PHP will only process the last one.

Comment: Ah okay, makes sense (I haven't used an actual HTML form in years ...)

Comment: @DainisAbols This doesn't seem to be the same as that question at all, this is specific to the use of the `MULTIPLE` attribute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the proper `enctype` to be able to upload files.

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="save.php">
```

Comment: Thanks! That helped! Now, I am having trouble with moving the file. I am getting the error ' move_uploaded_file() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given' Do you know why?

Comment: Try to do it in the loop.
move_uploaded_file()  for each file you upload

Comment: @user1759682: When you upload multiple files, every key in `$_FILES['uploads']` is an array (just like `$_FILES['uploads']['name']`).

Comment: move_uploaded_file($file, $target)

Comment: @user1759682 could you provide more info about error, so I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

try this html code:  `<form method="post" action="save.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">`
Then in PHP:

```
if(isset($_FILES['uploads'])){
foreach ($_FILES['uploads']['name'] as $file) {
    echo $file . "<br/>";
    $file= time() . $_FILES['uploads']['name'];
    $target= UPLOADPATH . $file;
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploads']['tmp_name'], $target)
    or die('error with query 2');
   }
} else {
   echo 'some error message!';
}
```

Comment: `$_FILES['uploads']['name']` and `$_FILES['uploads']['tmp_name']` are actually arrays.

Answer (score 0):

In order to upload files in the first place, you need `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on your `<form>` tag.

But, when you upload multiple files, every key in `$_FILES['uploads']` is an array (just like `$_FILES['uploads']['name']`).

You need to get the array key when looping, so you can process each file.  See the [docs for `move_uploaded_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) for more deatils.

```
<?php
  foreach ($_FILES['uploads']['name'] as $key=>$file) {
    echo $file."<br/>";
    $file = time().$file;
    $target = UPLOADPATH.$file;
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploads']['tmp_name'][$key], $target)
    or die('error with query 2');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

index.html

```
<form method="post" action="save.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="uploads[]" multiple="multiple" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload Image"/>
</form>
```

save.php

```
<?php    
  $file_dir  = "uploads";    
  if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {

    for ($x = 0; $x < count($_FILES['uploads']['name']); $x++) {                

      $file_name   = time() . $_FILES['uploads']['name'][$x];
      $file_tmp    = $_FILES['uploads']['tmp_name'][$x];

      /* location file save */
      $file_target = $file_dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file_name;

      if (move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file_target)) {                        
        echo "{$file_name} has been uploaded. <br />";                      
      } else {                      
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading {$file_name}.";   
      }                 

    }               
  }    
?>
```